# MongoDB-Rails: insert a json into db using mongomapper and retriving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I am completely new to Rails and MongoDB. I am using Rails-3 and MongoDB with **MongoMapper** to create a small application which stores some data and returns the data in json format. The client expects the json in a particular format. But I am not able to create the same format in the saved document.

**Reqd Format:**

```
{"Name":"ABC","max":{"key":"KEY-1","value":"100"},"min":{"key":"KEY-2","value":"0"}}
```

**Parent Doc**

```
class Story
 include MongoMapper::Document
 key :item,     String
 key :max,      
 key :min,      
end
```

What I want is to create a document {"key":"KEY-1","value":"100"} first and then map that document to the parent document's **max** key and similarly another document to the **min** key.

I tried many ways, but I am not able to make it work.

Also,
The I want to remove the field **id** (object id) from the response JSON while returning to the client. 
**Sample JSON:**

```
{"id":"51e64bce44ae8bf1fea3f78f","text":"Text 1","value":"Value 1"}
```

How can i do that?

**Update**
Answering one of my own question : "Removing the non-required fields from the json response"

It can be done by defining the as_json method inside the Model class. This will add only the fields 'key' and 'value' to the generated json.

```
def as_json(options={}){
   :key  =>self.key,
   :value => self.value
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question:
I searched around and couldn't find any satisfactory answer for my question.

On a temporary basis, I had created hash for the inner class and was assigning the value. This was a temporary solution which is little dirty.

I had posted the same question to a mongomapper group and got the answer. Sharing that answer here..

Assume that I have a model called **Inner** and another called **Outer**

```
one :max, :class_name => Inner
```

This will embed the **Inner** class object to the **max** attribute of the **Outer** class